# How to restrict user to file upload in php ?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I have searched on this site and google. I found a lots of suggestion about php upload restriction for user upload. 
Such as, check extension, [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

or read file data and check if it is legal image or not etc etc.

But my thinking is: if i create a `.htaccess` to execute only img file and rename the uploaded file then is it not enough for security ?

What's your opinion ?

Comment: executing an image file sounds not good to me, what do you actually want to say?

Comment: Why don't you check out http://www.uploadify.com/ if you're after a decent uploader. Otherwise your question doesn't really tell us what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Ok, mean it, not execute any non-image file.
I actually want to say that , is my thinking is enough for this kinds of security. I am not challenging anyone. It's all about my thinking. @Andy

Answer (score -1):

with html 5 you can use the 'accept' attribute to restrict uploads to only be images or audio or video or mime_type.

Comment: If that would be sufficient, most of the wordpress hacks wouldn't work. It is all about: “Do not trust the input”. That HTML5-option is client-side, so the server cannot rely on that.